# String count without using ".length" or ".size" methods?

Tags: ruby, string

I am new to the ruby and was practicing a code. I want to count the letters in a string by a self written code, without using `#length` or `#size` method. I have searched online but am unable to find anything relating to my query. I would appreciate if anyone could help me out in this simple program.

Comment: Search online for loops in Ruby.

Comment: Check `each_char`, `each_byte` or maybe `split`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other option, mapping [String#chars](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/String.html#method-i-chars) with index then picking the last:

```
str = "123456"
str.chars.map.with_index { |_, i| i + 1 }.last
#=> 6
```

It generates an Array, but we are not looking for efficiency here.

---

Or even using [String#index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/String.html#method-i-index) with offset:

```
str = "aaaa"
str.index(str[-1], -1) + 1
#=> 4
```

It looks for the index of the latest char starting from the end.

Comment: Here's another you could add to your collection: `str = "bulldog"; str =~ /#{str}/; Regexp.last_match.end(0) #=> 7`.

Comment: Nice @CarySwoveland! I'm still trying to understand how is working.. I'm really not a regexp guy :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using any `String` method that enumerates characters. The most obvious is [String#each_char](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-each_char), as @knut mentioned in a comment.

```
def str_length(str)
  enum = str.each_char
  n = 0
  loop do
    enum.next
    n += 1
  end
  n
end
```

```
str_length "Zaphod"
  #=> 6
```

Let's see what is happening here.

```
str = "Zaphod"
enum = str.each_char
  #=> #<Enumerator: "123456":each_char> 
n = 0

loop do
  s = enum.next
  n += 1
  puts "s = #{s}, n = #{n}"
end
n #=> 6
```

prints

```
s = Z, n = 1
s = a, n = 2
s = p, n = 3
s = h, n = 4
s = o, n = 5
s = d, n = 6
```

See [Enumerator#next](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-next). After `enum.next #=> "d"` is executed `enum.next` is executed once more, raising a `StopIteration` exception. That exception is handled by [Kernel#loop](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) by breaking out of the loop.

As I said at the outset, any `String` method could be used that enumerates characters. For example, `enum = str.gsub(/./)`.

The same approach could be used for any class that implements a method that enumerates elements of a collection. For example, we could add a method to the `Enumerable` module, which would then be available for every class that includes that module.

```
module Enumerable
  def my_length
    enum = each
    n = 0
    loop do
      enum.next
      n += 1
    end
    n
  end
end
```

```
[1,2,3,4].my_length
  #=> 4 
{ a: 1, b: 2 }.my_length
  #=> 2 
(1..5).my_length 
  #=> 5
```